# I have egregiously sloppy (possibly falsified) data that I need to correct. How should I go about this?

Tags: research-undergraduate, research-misconduct

Several years ago, I did a summer project as an undergrad with a PI not at my undergrad institution (I'm in grad school now). Now, the project is finished and he wants to publish it with data that I've gathered.

The problem is, after checking my data, that the spreadsheets that I used to calculate the data are very inaccurate, to say the least. I can't remember exactly what I did, but there do seem to be some egregious inaccuracies (as in, values from the wrong dataset) in my spreadsheet compared to the raw data from the instrument either that I was colossally bad at copying data over correctly (all of the data in my spreadsheet do appear in the raw data someplace, but not necessarily in the right location, the right dataset, etc.), or worse, I'm terrified that I may have done it deliberately at the time. (How would someone be able to tell?) I did analysis with the faulty data back then and produced graphs.

Obviously, I will have to supply the correct data analysis before it gets published. But is it ok to explain it as "I majorly screwed up the analysis and made a lot of data entry errors, here's the corrected version"? I'm hoping that my PI will just use my corrected data and analysis and just focus on that instead trying to pore over my wrong spreadsheets to individually compare all the changes, many of which are embarrassing at best and look suspicious at worst. I am not under any suspicion of wrongdoing thus far.

I redid my data analysis with correct data entry and the results look messier on most of the things I messed up, though they do not affect the underlying trends. Not sure what this means - how likely is it for honest error to have the effect of making data look cleaner than it actually is? Also, my god, I was awful - mishmashing data from one trial with another, copying data from the wrong wavelengths and/or from the wrong trial, wrong normalization numbers, etc. etc. etc.

If you were a professor and you were approached by a student who says that made egregious errors on past data analysis and the corrected data looks not nearly as good, what would you think? Would you think they were honestly trying to fix a mistake, or trying to save face and cover for past misconduct?

Comment: How is it that your own data dwell in some Schrödinger-esque contraption in which they are either falsified or merely erroneous? Do you mean to say you've actually falsified these data but are trying to be coy and test whether it can go unnoticed as you correct them? Or looking for a reason to keep it in the altered form?

Comment: A bit of a tangential point, but this is also why you should not be doing data work in spreadsheets.  Data work should be done through code, without altering the originals, so that it can be reproduced and audited.

Comment: @Jeff This. Data should be always available in the original raw form as it was created by the measurement device or at the time of the experiment. That version of data goes into Fort Knox and is *never ever* modified.

Comment: I never modified the original raw data. I did egregiously miscopy that raw data into spreadsheets where I do my calculations.

Comment: I find it hard to believe your implication that you do not know whether you deliberately mishandled the data in the past. Do you have any reason for not knowing for sure?

Comment: @user21820 I did this research more than half a decade ago. I had to email my former PI just to have the data since I no longer had it. When I saw it, I couldn't believe the inaccuracies in my spreadsheets - while I did not alter any of the original raw data, I often miscopied the data into the spreadsheets to such an extent that I found it difficult to believe that it was ordinary carelessness. The graphs also seemed a bit nicer with the inaccurate data entry/analysis.

Comment: @8263xiao: Hmm. I don't have a problem remembering whether I was deliberately dishonest or not, even a decade ago. From your last comment, it sounds like you do not have a habit of being dishonest, and you do not remember intentionally being dishonest. If that is so, take it at face value, because carelessness can cause a huge amount of errors. In particular, a mouse-slip might cause an entire chunk of text to be dragged from one point to another, and if middle-click does a paste operation then an accidental middle-click can overwrite data with data from somewhere else without you knowing.

Comment: People who has perfect memory cannot get this. I totally can. Many times in my life including when I was young, I had situations where I could not remember some pieces of information, other people would deem "impossible to forget". One of the situation was very similar, I was accused of a misconduct, and I could not remember the exact chain of events, that would clear my name, I could not confidently say I did not do it. I suffered the punishment, and then a witness that was unwilling to come forward during the process, approached me and informed me that I in fact did not do it. It does happen

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I agree completely. I am capable of forgetting not only what day and month it is, but what I did that morning. This is not an unbelievable story.

Comment: Using or not using Excel vs retaining the original raw data have nothing to do with each other.  It has to do with using proper methodology, not what tool you are using.  And also, Excel formulas *are* code (and I say that as a professional programmer).

Comment: Anything like "I majorly screwed up the analysis and made a lot of data-entry errors…" will stand only to your shame.

"That version was corrupted. Here's the corrected version…" should work.

None of that changes the fact that your exposition might look detailed but in fact, it's merely wordy…

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: Did you ever have any situations where you didn't remember if you *intended* to engage in misconduct? It's one thing to not know whether you *are* doing it (even in the *present* you might not know whether something constitutes misconduct...), it's another thing to not know whether you *intended* to engage in misconduct.

Comment: @user541686: As Andrew writes, it may be difficult for people with good memories to “get” how this kind of bad memory can work. In my adult professional life I’ve never committed such misconduct; but in high school, I did (if I remember right) fabricate data on a couple of science projects/assignments, and in undergrad, I remember at least being tempted to do it again on one project. I don’t think I did in the end, but I don’t remember for sure.  It’s hard to distinguish in memory between the feeling of serious temptation/considering it, and actually doing it.

Comment: @BryanKrause  one way I could see it happening would be to intermingle test data with real data.  If the OP was using modified copies of the real data to test various cases within their analysis path and was sloppy about keeping track of which files were which when copying data around.  Similar to  Andrew Savinykh; after 6 years I could see myself wondering if maybe I wasn't just way sloppier than I thought possible but in a moment of stupidity/insanity did something worse and then dumped all recollection down a self sealing memory hole.

Comment: While the only consequences to me were just a trip to the ER and a permanent scar, I managed to bury the fact that a childhood accident whose circumstances made no sense was that rather than pushing back on bad how to instructions (to swing a hammer with my right hand despite being left handed) I did something that I thought would just result in an "OWWW!" after which my point for "that's the wrong way to do it" would have been made for about 25 years.

Answer (score 55):

I infer from the question that you still have the raw data. In that case, I think you need to re-do all the steps in which errors could be introduced (such as data entry, spread-sheet calculations, analysis of trends). Then see what effect the corrections have on the conclusions of your paper, and rewrite as necessary. I realize that this sounds like a lot of work, essentially repeating most of what you had done earlier, but since you apparently did it wrong the first time, you now need to do it right.

Meanwhile, you should tell the PI about the problem and your plans for correcting it. If I correctly understand the situation, the raw data are the only reliable information currently available. You should make sure he knows that, so that he (and others working with him) won't build further research on a foundation of wrong results.

Comment: I do still have the raw data, and I did redo the analyses prior to asking my question. Most of the errors were in the data entry - copy/pasting numbers from the wrong places, and there was quite a lot of that such that it's almost inexplicable. The effect was that the trends stayed the same but the error got bigger. There were other things I had to do with the spreadsheets, such as re-organizing and making a new graph, so I just sent him the spreadsheets/graphs I corrected. Hopefully he takes it well and doesn't react with anger or suspicion of previous wrongdoing.

Comment: And, most importantly, stop doing science with spreadsheets

Answer (score 17):

Everyone will have their own reaction, of course, but the more important thing is that you point out the errors and the need to correct them. Going forward with bad data is the worst outcome.

Work up the best data you can and tell the prof that the older data was seriously flawed.

I think most people will accept your honesty, even if it means some delay. And most will forgive at least some of it due to your lack of experience at the time.

Hopefully the original data is still available making corrections possible.

But, you also need to be honest with yourself about how this all happened. I can think of a few very bad scenarios that I hope weren't contributing factors. There are actual medical conditions that might have such an effect. You don't want a recurrence.

Comment: I did. Hopefully that will satisfy him. My previous work was admittedly atrocious (I was definitely a very sloppy undergrad), and my fear of suspicion is because the corrected data looks messier and has much larger error bars.

Comment: @Buffy If the internship was relevant to a grade or a reference, the discovery of fabrication of data may unravel the conditions for OP being in grad school. It is very much to be hoped that the data were just misgenerated in a fit of sleep deprivation rather than in an act of intentional fabrication. I know that I would wash my hands off a student that I suspect of previously fabricating data. This is the one capital scientific misconduct that a reputation can not recover from, in my opinion.

Comment: How would such an act of fabrication be proven vs. genuine error? Also, I already sent him the corrected data analysis - how would a PI react to their former student saying they made a lot of mistakes in data analysis and provided corrections? The raw data is unaltered and available.

Comment: "And most will forgive at least some of it due to your lack of experience at the time." I think so, too, but publishing data generated by an undergraduate student without double checking is also a mistake, maybe also caused by lack of experience. Both student and advisor will have learned something from this. (Not saying anything about the intentional vs. accidental discussion which can only be decided by looking at the actual data.)

Comment: A mistake is unfortunate, fabrication is evil. Intentions matter. If it was a mistake, it's still not nice (it is a nuisance to have sloppy collaborators, but if they learn to become more careful, one may accept that they improved). Bad intentions will however leave an ever-lingering suspiciion.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, I took "falsification" as hyperbole based on fear rather than fact. But, yes, intentional falsification is of a different order than sloppiness.

Comment: @Buffy It's the OP's own words. I must confess I find it hard to put myself in the shoes of someone who does not even remember how their data came about. I remember the circumstances about the development of practically every paper I did as a first/main author. That's why I suspected that the situation might be the result of lack of sleep (or otherwise under extreme time pressure).

Answer (score 9):

I'll take your questions one at a time.

> I'm terrified that I may have done it deliberately at the time. (How would someone be able to tell?)

I'm not sure if by "someone" you mean you, or the person you send this to.  I can definitely imagine looking back at my own work from undergrad and doubting the integrity of it if it looked fishy.  If I were trying to figure out whether I had done it intentionally, I would look for patterns in the errors (e.g. maybe treatment group is only ever misrecorded for data points that pattern against the tested hypothesis), and see if they jog your memory.  I suppose that's probably what I'd do if I were trying to figure out whether someone else had done something intentional, but I seriously doubt most people would bother.

> But is it ok to explain it as "I majorly fucked up the analysis and made a lot of data entry errors, here's the corrected version"?

Absolutely.  You were an undergrad and it's the prof's responsibility to check your work and to ensure you know what you're doing.  Also, the unfortunate reality is that lots of profs intentionally teach students in their labs to mishandle data to "improve" results, so that's a potential explanation here too.  Because of that, I'd be more likely to say something like "Looking back at the data now, I'm finding a lot of errors, so many that I don't think correcting them is feasible, so unfortunately I believe that this data would have to be reanalysed from scratch to proceed with the project." That is, tread lightly if you can't recall the origin of the discrepancies, but make your own position clear.

Also, it is absolutely not your responsibility to provide corrected data if you don't want to continue with the project.  I assume as an undergrad you were either paid or volunteering in exchange for the training/experience, and I assume neither of those is true of your relationship with this PI/lab now.  I recommend asking yourself whether you honestly want to continue with this project before putting any more work into this.

> I redid my data analysis with correct data entry and the results look messier on most of the things I messed up, though they do not affect the underlying trends. Not sure what this means - how likely is it for honest error to have the effect of making data look cleaner than it actually is?

More likely than not.  Unfortunately, we're a lot more likely to double-check steps in our work if we don't like the look of the data, no matter how thorough/neutral we might intend to be.

> If you were a professor and you were approached by a student who says that made egregious errors on past data analysis and the corrected data looks not nearly as good, what would you think? Would you think they were honestly trying to fix a mistake, or trying to save face and cover for past misconduct?

Depends on the student and the professor. Personally I trust the students that I work with or I wouldn't be working with them, so I would believe them.  And I promise you, every researcher has encountered egregious errors in their past work at one point or another, often at this very stage of preparing/doublechecking for publication.

Comment: Now looking back again, the most suspicious thing I saw in the data was that I had copied only some of the results of different trial into a spreadsheet for a particular trial. While certainly that is possible with error (I may have had both trials' raw data open at the time and thus it was possible to mix up), there were more data points in the trial I erroneously copied from, which resulted in the original trial having more points than it actually did, matching the other trial. 1/

Comment: It's possible that when I was analyzing the data I misremembered the setups for each trial and thought they were both the same, and I may have set up my spreadsheet that way and the mixups gave me the wrong impression that I had the additional points for both. But that does look suspicious. For my corrected version, I just reported fewer data points, consistent with what I saw in the correct raw data. It didn't really change the overall results but did make them a bit more noisy. 2/

Comment: My former PI never delved into the spreadsheets or compared them to raw data; I only showed him graphs. I don't think he ever pressured me to "improve" results per se, though as an undergrad I was definitely very insecure, eager to please, but not particularly professional/competent. I do want to get this published, but certainly not with bad data. I do have the original raw data that I now analyzed correctly, and I told him I found a number of errors in my past analysis. Hopefully he believes me and looks mainly at the updated/new analysis without delving into the past too much. /3

Comment: I think my PI trusts me, perhaps undeservedly so back then as an undergrad. It is absolutely my responsibility to correct the data because it will be reflected in the scientific record and not doing so would tarnish us both. I just hope that he trusts that I'm now on top of things and that he's not painstakingly combing through what I already told him is invalid analysis, for both our sakes. /fin

Comment: If you can't remember what happened, I'd give yourself the benefit of the doubt and assume it was an honest mistake unless and until you discover evidence to the contrary. Basically treat your work as you would someone else's. It's really no different at this point, since you can't remember what you did. Your work is as much a black box to you as someone else's would be.

Comment: @bob What would be evidence to the contrary?

Comment: I'm not sure honestly. Notes in the Excel workbook that indicate dishonest intent ("round down to minimize appearance of errors")? Maybe someone else could comment here? But basically if it doesn't scream "this looks like academic dishonesty", I'd take a deep breathe and relax. It probably wasn't. This of course is taking at face value an inability to remember what happened.

Comment: @8263xiao: Since your bad data never got published, any mistakes (intentional or otherwise) are at least semi-private, and in your past.  Clearly you know better *now*, and can just start fresh from the raw data (which you know hasn't been intentionally tampered with), with better analysis tools and methodology that you've learned since then.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the issue is, now looking back at it again, that the data inaccuracies are very suspicious and could be consistent with misconduct; if someone meticulously combs through my old spreadsheets, that is a conclusion they could easily draw as the inaccuracies made the graphs look better. It is true that the scientific record will not be tainted by this, and I was not stupid/malicious enough to tamper with raw data. 1/

Comment: @PeterCordes So I did start fresh from the raw data and redid everything. I had changes I wanted to make to the analysis anyways because I learned a lot in the years after that project. It's just that the possibility that based on my past inaccuracies someone could reasonably conclude that I was acting dishonorably, even if I am not doing so now, even if I already informed my PI my past spreadsheets were flawed and their contents should not be the basis of the paper, that worries me. /fin